# Tkinter function call does not return value

Tags: python, function, tkinter, execution, mainloop

I intend to collect names in lists that will be used in a program, one at a time. The function does return a list and the whole program runs once, but after I call the function UserInput with the button:

```
ttk.Button(root, text='Add place', command= lambda:UserInput()).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10)
```

it remains hanging. Even if I close the window, the program doesn't move to the next line:

```
print('outside function',  places)
```

anymore.

The code is:

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import simpledialog

from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

def UserInput():

    places = []

    while True:

        place = simpledialog.askstring('Input', 'Enter name',
                                parent=root)

        if place == None: # 'Cancel'
            continue

        if place == '':  
            break  
        else:
            places.append(place)
    print(places)      

    return(places)

places = (UserInput())  # list of cities to visit

print('outside function',  places)


ttk.Button(root, text='Add place', command= lambda:UserInput()).pack(ipadx=10, ipady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: when testing:]

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Remove the while loop and replace `continue` and `break` with `pass`

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation. It does lead to a solution with a different outcome. I am looking for a solution to be able to enter several strings into a list, and to do this again and again whenever calling the function with a button.

Comment: The return value from a callback triggered by button will be discarded because there is no receiver.  Actually `places` can be declared as global and so it can be accessed elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your help. This got me further. Now, what do I need to change so that the line "print('outside function',  places)" executes every time I call the function with the button.